# Flutter/Dart - Get index number of PageView.Builder for use in a Text Widget?

Tags: flutter, variables, dart, flutter-pageview

I've got a `PageView.builder` within a `StatelessWidget`. I need to get the current index number of the currently viewed page to appear in a text widget in my build.

Was hoping I could simply use `currentIndex.toString()` as a variable in the text widget but Android Studio underlines it in red and warns me of `undefined name currentIndex`. How can I get the correct variable?

```
 class StageBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<SpeakContent> speakcrafts;
  StageBuilder(this.speakcrafts);

  final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: speakcrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget createViewItem(SpeakContent speakcraft, BuildContext context) {
  
    return Container(
        child: Text(currentIndex.toString()),
     )     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `currentIndex` into your `createViewItem`

```dart
 class StageBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<SpeakContent> speakcrafts;
  StageBuilder(this.speakcrafts);

  final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: speakcrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context, currentIndex);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget createViewItem(SpeakContent speakcraft, BuildContext context, int currentIndex) {
  
    return Container(
        child: Text(currentIndex.toString()),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this but got a red underlining everything in the brackets. return createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context, currentIndex);

Comment: Apologies, I forgot the 2nd part.